# Why am I not allowed to have multiple assignments in for each loop with different lengths of lists in python

Tags: python

Just like I'm allowed to do this:

(EDIT - I'm NOT allowed to do this either, sorry messed up, but anyway I guess my question is more on the lines of how to go about doing parallel assignments in a loop)

```
for (x,i) in ([0,1,2],[3,4,5]):
  # do something
```

why am I not allowed to do this in a for each loop (different list length)

```
 for (x,i) in ([4,6,5,7,8,9],[1,2,3]):
   # do something
```

I know you get a "ValueError: too many values to unpack", but why doesn't the loop stop when i is done with its iteration?

A real use of this would be for something like this that I was trying to do

```
for (keys,i) in (sorted(dic.keys(),key=custom_sort), range(10)):
  print dic[keys]
```

where I'm sorting the dictionary as well as printing only the first 10 top results (assume the dictionary has hundreds of keys) - I only wanted the top 10 results.

Since this kind of syntax is not allowed anyway what could be the next best thing to do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of stuff, [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) is your friend.

In your case, [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) will do the trick:

```
import itertools
for key in itertools.islice(sorted(dict.keys(), key=custom_sort), 10):
    # Only the first 10 keys are processed.
```

Alternatively, if you need the index as well, use `zip` or `itertools.izip`:

```
for i, key in zip(range(10), sorted(dict.keys(), key=custom_sort)):
    # i will be 0, 1, ..., 9
```

Comment: +1: You clearly know your Python recipes far better than I do!

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* do what you do in your first example - it gives exactly the same error. So the error isn't from the lists being different lengths at all.

I think what you mean to do is this:

```
for (x,i) in zip([0,1,2],[3,4,5]):
```

which works just as well with lists of different lengths

```
>>> for x, i in zip([4,6,5,7,8,9],[1,2,3]):
...   print x, i
... 
4 1
6 2
5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to do this:

```
for (x,i) in ([0,1,2],[3,4,5]):
  # do something
```

Comment: I swear i tried this in interpretor before posting the question and now it doesn't work, damn! the laws of programming be a harsh mistress

Comment: so anyway, what could be the best way to go about parallel assignment in a loop?

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (x,i) in ([0,1,2],[3,4,5]):
    # do something
```

Will `raise`:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

It looks like you are trying to do this:

```
>>> import itertools as i
>>> first,second = [4,6,5,7,8,9],[1,2,3]
>>> for x,i in i.izip(first, second):
...     print x, i
... 
4 1
6 2
5 3
```

Take a look at [`itertools`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/itertools.html), specifically [`izip()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). There's a wealth of goodness therein... for instance, the `islice()` function, in [Ferdinand Beyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882346/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-have-multiple-assignments-in-for-each-loop-with-different/6882366#6882366) and other [recipes](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Answer (score 0):

`for` iterates over the elements in the container.  Each element is a single list with greater than two elements.

Try this:

```
(x, y) = ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5])
```

Which is what you want.  No need for the `for`.

Note that your first example that you claim works doesn't actually.  You can't do:

```
for (x, y) in ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]):
    pass
```

You get the same error.